# create virtuemart frontend page templates

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I want to create a page in virtuemart frontend, so i can show some product information according to client requirement. How the virtuemart frontend page templates fetched for frontend page.
Have any document and blog, which provide instruction for create virtuemart frontend page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Virtuemart has a templating system that works within the component. In VM they call them themes. The VM documentation covers most everything you will need to get started. I will warn you however that VM themes are fairly complicated and hard to understand.

Recently I have started using the K2 extension with the K2Mart plugin so that all of the product display chores are handled by K2, VM just handles the checkout process. K2 templating is much easier to work with since the standard Joomla override rules apply. It is a huge time saver when it comes to customizing product display. K2Mart is a commercial extension, but well worth the price.